# Django shell ORA-00904

Tags: sql, django, oracle, django-models

I have a legacy database from oracle that has fields. If I run Orders.objects.count() I get the correct amount. When I run Orders.object.all() I get this error but haven't found a solution online.

`class Orders(models.Model):`
    `account_obj_db = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)`
    `account_obj_id0 = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)`
    `account_obj_type = models.CharField(max_length=1020, blank=True, null=True)`
    `account_obj_rev = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)`
    `order_payload_buf_size = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)`
    `total_entitlement_count = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)`
    `currency_code = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)`

`>>> from home.models import Orders`
`>>> Orders.objects.all()`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/dev2/lib/python3.5/site-            packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/user/dev2/lib/python3.5/site-    packages/django/db/backends/oracle/base.py", line 481, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, self._param_generator(params))
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00904: "ORDERS"."ID": invalid identifier

Comment: Please add some sample rows

Comment: Sounds like the models and the database table aren't matching, you can either migrate to make sure they are matching or edit the models like the table in your database

Comment: Since my table doesnt have a primary key I believe Django is creating the ID field. In the documentation I dont see a way around the autofields. Any idea? @Mojimi

Comment: @AlleeClark I also had a similar issue with legacy databases, so yes you need a primary key, create that constraint on one of the fields of your table in the database, and add the primary_key = true parameter to that same field in the models, you might need to migrate again

Comment: @Mojimi You were right. I had to add the primary keys. I'm not sure if you would like to add an answer for me to select. It will help people who are struggling to serialize data from a legacy database.

Comment: @AlleeClark done, with a better explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that, when you don't assign a primary key to your models, Django will create a "ID" PK field that is not shown on models.

But when you set `managed = false`(I assume you did) in your model's meta, Django will not create/manage this table in the database, meaning it will not create the underlying ID pk field, but the model level still thinks it exists (you could consider this a bug and report it) and tries to make queries with it, hence the ORA error

The solution is to manually set the same PK field in your models as you have in your database, let's say `account_obj_db` is the PK field of `Orders` in your legacy Database, just add primary_key to it in your models.py :

```
class Orders(models.Model):
    account_obj_db = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key = true, blank=True, null=True)
    account_obj_id0 = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    account_obj_type = models.CharField(max_length=1020, blank=True, null=True)
    account_obj_rev = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    order_payload_buf_size = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    total_entitlement_count = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    currency_code = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

You might need to do another migration after this

Also watch your indenting

Comment: A big gotcha with this is when your legacy database uses composite keys and not a single column as Django is still beholden to a single ID column.